# Why ScriptEngine has not Execute method anymore?

Tags: c#, roslyn

Currently I've started to work with Roslyn more seriously.
I found [this article](http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2011/11/16/the-roslyn-scripting-api.aspx) about using `ScriptEngine` on Eric Vogel's blog.
Due his blog, there should be an `Execute` method in this class:

```
scriptEngine.Execute("1+1");
```

But it seems it doesn't exist anymore.
Where does it gone?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It was moved to the session object.  First you need to

```
var session = engine.CreateSession(SomeHostObject);
session.Execute("some code");
```

Though it should be noted Roslyn has been released as Microsoft.CodeAnalysis now and they "temporarily" removed scripting all together. See from the [FAQ](http://roslyn.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=FAQ&referringTitle=Home#Scripting,%20REPL,%20and%20Executing%20Code%20Questions)

Comment: You can still get it via NuGet too : Install-Package Roslyn -Version 1.2.20906.2