# C# Roslyn Execute

Tags: c#, execute, roslyn

```
using Roslyn.Compilers;
using Roslyn.Scripting.CSharp;

ScriptEngine scriptEngine = new ScriptEngine();
try
{
    object result = scriptEngine.Execute(txtSource.Text);
    txtOutput.Text = result + "";
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    txtOutput.Text = ex.Message;
}
```

> Error  1   'Roslyn.Scripting.CSharp.ScriptEngine' does not contain a definition for 'Execute' and no extension method 'Execute' accepting a first argument of type 'Roslyn.Scripting.CSharp.ScriptEngine' 
>   could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why ScriptEngine has not Execute method anymore?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22880549/why-scriptengine-has-not-execute-method-anymore)

Answer (score 0):

```
 var engine = new ScriptEngine();
 var session = engine.CreateSession();            
 var result = session.Execute("1+1");
```